# PHP - function name conflicts

Tags: php, wordpress, function

so I'm using Wordpress, which loads the theme and possibly many plugins which can have functions with the same names as the ones in the theme.

How can I avoid function name conflicts between the theme and plugins, without having to rename them to something like "theme_function()"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really. You need to rename your functions in a way they don't collide with any other function. Prefixing functions with your theme's name sounds pretty clean and optimal.

Possible other workarounds that come to mind are

- Using a static class `Theme` and adding any functions to that (`Theme::function();`)- not much different from adding a `theme_` prefix to normal function names, though
- Once PHP 5.3 is widely spread in a few years, you can use [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en//language.namespaces.php) - it's too early at the moment, though, if you want to build redistributable themes or plugins.

Answer (score 1):

**Rename them.** It's easy. The theme functions are in theme folder's `functions.php` file. You *must* rename them to avoid conflict.

Other way is to use [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) but that would take more effort, IMO, then just rename a handful of functions.

Answer (score 0):

could also use `function_exists()`

```
if(!function_exists('parse_markdown'))
{

    function parse_markdown($markdown)
    {
      return $markdown;
    }
}
```